# Can I export my real estate listings via my own custom IDX?

Tags: php, wordpress, idx

Can I export my real estate listings from my website via my own custom IDX so that I can import them on my other real estate websites?

If yes, where can I learn IDX?

I know IDX is officially an API but I also read that it follows a syntax and that it functions like a programming language. So can you clear me up on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RETS api of your MLS to pull out your own listings (as often others as well). AFAIK, that's actually what IDX relies on. [Bridge has a Java based SDK](http://www.bridgeinteractive.com/resources-topic-pagerets-sdk/) that's fairly easy to use, and I've seen ones for PHP and so forth as well. I mainly have experience with the Bridge SDK. You can actually pull data just using your browser as well [using this tutorial](https://www.flexmls.com/developers/rets/tutorials/example-rets-session/). RETS uses a query language called DMQL that's fairly straightforward which you can learn about [here](https://www.flexmls.com/developers/rets/tutorials/dmql-tutorial/). You'll need to know your login information as well as the URL to the rets server your MLS provides. Assuming you're a real estate agent within your MLS and you already have a membership with them you probably know this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand  IDX you mean RETS Service?  IDX is services that 3rd party set everything for you.

you can use their services for a monthly fee. Zoopify.com provides Free IDX services send an email to info@zoopify.com it will take some time but they will Set Free Services for you, Or you can use free open Source RETS Client that pull RETS data from your local MLS. AND set your Custom solution.
check out: phrets